# Changing a node in hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

We have the code uploading config file to HDFS:

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient

def upload_file_to_hdfs(local_path, remote_path):
    client = InsecureClient(url='http://hdfs_server:50070', user='dr.who')
    try:
        ret = client.upload(remote_path, local_path)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(f'Error: {e}')
    print(f'File is uploaded: {local_path} -> {remote_path}')
    return ret
```

Now the domain name and port are fixed. What to do if we have a node being switched?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you use pyarrow / snakebite / libhdfs , which I think offer non WebHDFS/HTTP functions to write files.

But, you should setup Namenode HA and use a nameservice or DNS hostname to find the current, available namenode. Obviously, if you change every namenode, you'll need to edit the code... You'll also have other HDFS downtime while the namenode(s) are replaced

You could also use an environment variable or config file to externalize your string from the function itself